# getting error callback is not a function in one condition

Tags: jquery, callback

I have two functions like this

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnEdit", function (e) {
    TransactionId = $(this).closest("div").find('#SearchItemID').text();

    EditorDuplicate(TransactionId);
});

$("body").on("click", "#btnDuplicate", function (e) {
    TransactionId = $(this).closest("div").find('#SearchItemID').text();

    EditorDuplicate(TransactionId);
    GetnextItemCode();
})
```

As you can see in my first function I am calling only the `EditorDuplicate` function, but in the secont one i am calling another function after excecuting of first completes.

But to load the `GetnextItemCode` function after `EditorDuplicate` function I added callback function. Now it looks like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnTransactionEdit", function (e) {
    TransactionId = $(this).closest("div").find('#SearchItemID').text();
    EditorDuplicate(TransactionId);
});

$("body").on("click", "#btnDuplicate", function (e) {
    TransactionId = $(this).closest("div").find('#SearchItemID').text();

    EditorDuplicate(TransactionId, function () {
        GetnextItemCode();
    });

    //EditorDuplicate(TransactionId);
    //GetnextItemCode();
})
```

EditorDuplicate function:

```
function EditorDuplicate(TransactionId, callback) {

    // other codes

    callback();
}
```

Now clicking `#btnDuplicate` works well, but when clicking `#btnEdit` I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Why is that? and how do I correct this?

**Note :**
And function is still not running one after another, `GetnextItemCode` executed before the other completes. `EditorDuplicate` function got several lines of codes, where `GetnextItemCode` function has only few lines.

**Please see the error in the snippet**

```js
// edit button
$("body").on("click", "#btnEdit", function () {
    var TransactionId = $('#SearchItemID').text();
    EditorDuplicate(TransactionId);
});

// duplicate button    
$("body").on("click", "#btnDuplicate", function () {
    var TransactionId = $('#SearchItemID').text();
     EditorDuplicate(TransactionId, function () {
        GetnextItemCode();
    });
});


function EditorDuplicate(TransactionId, callback) {

    alert("EditorDuplicate");
    // other codes

    callback();
}

function GetnextItemCode(){
    alert("GetnextItemCode")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="edit"/>
<input type="button" id="btnDuplicate" value="duplicate"/>

<br/><br/>
<span>Search Id :</span>
<span id="SearchItemID">2</span>
```

Comment: You can show us your HTML code, or much better give us a sample output using SO snippet

Comment: @alimbaronia please see the snippet added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you first need to check if `callback` is actually a function:

```
function EditorDuplicate(TransactionId, callback) {
    // your code

    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback();
    }
}
```

This is because `callback` becomes `undefined` when it is not passed in this call:

```
EditorDuplicate(TransactionId);
```

And trying to call `undefined` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

function EditorDuplicate(TransactionId, callback) {
    // your code

```
if (callback) {
  callback();
}
```

}